# How can I weld part to an admin page in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, orchardcms

In Orchard CMS, I can create a part and weld it to the site using `Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<TermsAndConditionSettingsPart>("Site"));` and have the editor for this part show up in the site settings.

I also have a few pages in my admin screens that I have used controllers and actions to allow the user edit settings for my modules.

I am wondering how I can weld a part onto one of my custom admin pages. I think I need to do something similar to the code mentioned above, but I'm not too sure what I should be welding to (ie- what should I replace "Site" with)? Do I need to create a content type for each of my admin pages?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After exploring further and taking into account @Piotr's excellent answer, I've managed to achieve what I wanted to do.

**Step 1: Migrations**

```
    private readonly IOrchardServices _services;

    public Migrations(IOrchardServices services) {
        _services = services;
    }

    public int Create() 
    {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("PlayerSearch", cfg => { });

        var content = _services.ContentManager.New("PlayerSearch");
        _services.ContentManager.Create(content);

        return 1;
    }
```

In the example above, `"PlayerSearch"` is the name of my content type (ie the item I will be welding my parts to). This code simply creates a `PlayerSearch` type and creates a single instance of it which is then persisted.

**Step 2: ContentPart**

I created a simple POCO class as a `ContentPart`. This is what I want to weld to my PlayerSearch page:

```
public class PlayerSearchPart : ContentPart
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }
    public string String3 { get; set; }
    public int Int1 { get; set; }
    public int Int2 { get; set; }
    public int Int3 { get; set; }      
}
```

**Step 3: ContentHandler**

The next thing I did, was to weld my `PlayerSearchPart` to my `PlayerSearch` type as defined in the migrations:

```
public class PlayerSearchHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public PlayerSearchHandler()
    {
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<PlayerSearchPart>("PlayerSearch"));
    }
}
```

I did this in the ContentHandler by using the `ActivatingFilter`.

**Step 4: The Controller**

Now we need to create a page in the admin screens that is capable of displaying all the welded parts to the user:

```
    private readonly IOrchardServices _services;

    public PlayerManagementController(IOrchardServices services) {
        _services = services;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PlayerSearch()
    {
        var playerSearchType = _services.ContentManager.Query().ForType(new[] {"PlayerSearch"}).Slice(0, 1).FirstOrDefault();
        var model = _services.ContentManager.BuildEditor(playerSearchType);

        // Casting to avoid invalid (under medium trust) reflection over the protected View method and force a static invocation.
        return View((object)model);
    }
```

This action retrieves the instance of my `PlayerSearch` type that I created in the Migrations file, builds the editor for it and then passes this to the view.

**Step 5: The View**

Our action of course needs a view, and it's pretty simple once you know how:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Display(Model.Content)
    <fieldset>
        <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">@T("Save")</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Step 6: The Driver**

Nothing out of the ordinary here:

```
    // GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(PlayerSearchPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_PlayerSearch_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                TemplateName: "Parts/PlayerSearch",
                Model: part,
                Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    // POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(PlayerSearchPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
```

**Step 7: Displaying the editor for your part**

The final step here is to create the editor template for your part, and to also ensure that you have a record in your `placement.info` for the part so that Orchard knows where to render it.

This technique was taken from the way that the site settings work. To have a look at this, and to see how the Post action would work too, have a look at the controller at `Orchard.Core.Settings.Controllers.AdminController`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot weld anything onto a custom page - it doesn't work like this.

Parts are welded onto content items, like `Site`. `Site` is no different from other content items, like `User`, `Page` etc., with one exception - there is always a single `Site` item per tenant. What you actually see when you go to any section in *Settings* is an editor for that item (and each section displays a part of that editor that corresponds to a named group). And this functionality is specific for `Site` items only.

If you need site-wide settings, the best way is to always weld parts onto `Site` item. Then you can provide links (or tabs etc.) that point to that specific editor from inside your custom views.